# BizTalk: Office365 Outlook Email - not member of SSO Administrators

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2016

In BizTalk 2016, when I enable a Receive Location using the adapter "Office365 Outlook Email", it raises an error message in the Application Event Log:

> Details "Service account does not have sufficient privileges. Please
> make sure the service account is a member of the SSO Administrators
> account.".

All our host instances run under an account that is BizTalk Admin, but probably not SSO Admin (I will get some with AD to verify).  If I remember, that is the minimal security needed.  Seems like a bad practice to add that user to SSO Administrator group.

So if I understand, the best practice might be to create another HostApp user account with BizTalk Admin and SSO just for this one adapter.  This sounds kind of crazy and overkill to me - but is that what would have to be done?